# Derivation of specific angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, vectors

When reviewing the derivation of specific angular momentum for an angular momentum balance of the annular control volume of an impeller,  ℏ , I have not been able to determine how the equation is derived:

ℒ /m = ℏ = ( ɽ X ν)
(specific angular momentum = cross product of position vector and velocity vector )

Shouldn’t the position vector be divided by m as or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Specific angular momentum is usually denoted as $h$, not $\hbar$.

Comment: Where did you find that equation? The cross product of position and momentum is the angular momentum, not the specific angular momentum.

Comment: Yes, the right side of the equation for specific angular momentum above should have been divided by m

Comment: You can edit your question to fix it.

Comment: Corrected - assumption was that both sides L and r X mv would be divided by m to attain ℎ

Comment: I’m unclear on what you don’t understand. The definition of angular momentum is the cross product of the position with the momentum. The definition of the specific angular momentum is the angular momentum divided by the mass. So why are you asking about this derivation? It simply combines two definitions.

Comment: Because mathematically if you divide both sides of L = r X mv, to me you would end up with L/m = (r X mv) / m = r/m X v instead of r X v

Comment: You appear to be having a difficulty with algebra, not with physics. The $m$’s in the numerator and denominator “cancel” because $m/m$ is 1.

Comment: Maybe it’s vector math that is preventing me from seeing this but I have (r X mv)/m  - yes the m/m cancels on mv/m to get v but the r should also be divided by m ? 
It’s (r X mv)/m not r X mv/m .

Comment: No, both vectors don’t get divided by $m$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties and note the part about “compatible with scalar multiplication”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113456/discussion-between-arinla-and-g-smith).

Comment: Left message, thanks again for the insight